# How can I run a MiniTab Executable file (.mtb) in vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform, commandbutton, minitab

Preferably I would like to incorporate it into a user form as a command button. 
The code I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub graphButton_Click()

    Dim mtbPath As String: mtbPath = "S:\MetLab (Protected)\MetLab Operations\Lab 
    Reports\Forgings"

    Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /s " & mtbPath & "\Updater.mtb", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Where Updater.mtb is the actual file I would like to execute.  This seems to only open Command prompt- which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Typically if a Shell argument has spaces you need to enclose it in double-quotes.  Try that first. `Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /s """ & mtbPath & "\Updater.mtb""", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: I now get a syntax error.

Comment: Is there a more simple way to go about this? I would just like a button on my user form which runs my executable minitab macro file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste into a VBA Module:

```
    Sub Run_Minitab_Macro()

    Set MtbApp = CreateObject("Mtb.Application")

    With MtbApp.ActiveProject
    'This lets you open an excel file from your desktop:
    .ExecuteCommand "WOpen 'C:\Users\you\Desktop\TEMP1.xlsx'; FType; Excel." 
    'Save the minitab project to my documents:
    .ExecuteCommand "Save  'C:\Users\you\My Documents\Test.MPJ'; Project; Replace."
    'On Error Resume Next
    .ExecuteCommand "%MacroFile" 'This is a .MAC macro file stored in the my 
                                 'documents folder saved to here, 
                                 'any command-line command can go here though
    'On Error GoTo 0
    .ExecuteCommand "Save."
    End With

    End Sub
```